# Incrementar name de input dinâmico com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um tabela que gera a linha dinamicamente ao clicar em um botão. Preciso que os names sejam incrementados ao gerar uma nova linha. Ex: name="product1" name="amount1" name="price1" name="total1" mudando apenas o número(1, 2, 3...) Como poderia fazer esse incremento? Tentei usar split para pegar um valor colocado na primeira vez que o botão é clicado mas so conseguir incrementar uma vez.

```
<table class="table m-0" id="products-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Produto/Serviço</th>
        <th>Quantidade</th>
        <th>Valor Unitário</th>
        <th>Valor Total</th>
        <th>Remover</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="row">

</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
            <button class="btn btn-info waves-effect w-md waves-light m-b-5" onclick="AddTableRow()" type="button">Adicionar Produto</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Jquery

```
<script>

RemoveTableRow = function(handler) {
    var tr = $(handler).closest('tr');
    tr.fadeOut(400, function() {
        tr.remove();
    });
    return false;
};

AddTableRow = function() {

    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";

    cols += '<td class="col-md-4"><input type="text" class="form-control product" name="product"></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control amount" name="amount"></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="price"></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-md-2 total"><input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="total"></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-md-2">';
    cols += '<a onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button"><i class="zmdi zmdi-delete zmdi-hc-lg"></i></a>';
    cols += '</td>';

    newRow.append(cols);
    $("#products-table").append(newRow);

    $(".amount, .price").unbind('blur keyup');
    $(".amount, .price").on("blur keyup",function(){
        const tr = $(this).parent().parent();

        const quant = parseInt(tr.find('.amount').val());
        const valor = parseInt(tr.find('.price').val());
        var total = quant * valor;

        if (!isNaN(quant) && !isNaN(valor)){
            tr.find('.total').html('<input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="total" value=" '+total+' ">');
        }
    });

    return false;
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para esse efeito pode-se construir um número no exterior da função:

```
let num = 1;
```

E utilizar dentro dela e ir aumentando o mesmo. Depois pode-se concatenar esse número diretamente no html construído com:

```
cols += '<td ... name="product' + num + '"></td>';
```

Juntando tudo:

```js
RemoveTableRow = function(handler) {
    var tr = $(handler).closest('tr');
    tr.fadeOut(400, function() {
        tr.remove();
    });
    return false;
};

let num = 1; //num criado aqui

AddTableRow = function() {

    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    
    var cols = "";

    cols += '<td class="col-md-4"><input type="text" class="form-control product" name="product' + num + '"></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control amount" name="amount' + num + '"></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="price' + num + '"></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-md-2 total"><input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="total' + num + '"></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-md-2">';
    cols += '<a onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button"><i class="zmdi zmdi-delete zmdi-hc-lg"></i></a>';
    cols += '</td>';

    num++; //numero aumenta aqui

    newRow.append(cols);
    $("#products-table").append(newRow);

    $(".amount, .price").unbind('blur keyup');
    $(".amount, .price").on("blur keyup",function(){
        const tr = $(this).parent().parent();

        const quant = parseInt(tr.find('.amount').val());
        const valor = parseInt(tr.find('.price').val());
        var total = quant * valor;

        if (!isNaN(quant) && !isNaN(valor)){
            tr.find('.total').html('<input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="total" value=" '+total+' ">');
        }
    });

    return false;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table m-0" id="products-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Produto/Serviço</th>
        <th>Quantidade</th>
        <th>Valor Unitário</th>
        <th>Valor Total</th>
        <th>Remover</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="row">

</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
            <button class="btn btn-info waves-effect w-md waves-light m-b-5" onclick="AddTableRow()" type="button">Adicionar Produto</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>



</script>
```

Esta solução garante que cada `name` é único mas não garante que é estritamente sequencial se forem entretanto removidas linhas no meio. Para garantir que ficam sequenciais, caso seja uma imposição do problema será necessário elaborar um pouco. Para isso podemos re-atribuir toda a numeração sempre que é inserida ou eliminada uma linha da tabela:

```
function ajustarNomes(){
    $(".table tr").each(function(indice){
        $(this).find('.product').attr("name", "product" + indice);
        $(this).find('.amount').attr("name", "amount" + indice);
        $(this).find('.price').attr("name", "price" + indice);
        $(this).find('.total').attr("name", "total" + indice);
    });
}
```

E agora chamar esta função cada vez que se insere ou remove linhas.

```js
function ajustarNomes(){
    $(".table tr").each(function(indice){
        //acha cada elemento de cada <tr> e coloca o name correto de acordo com o indice
        $(this).find('.product').attr("name", "product" + indice);
        $(this).find('.amount').attr("name", "amount" + indice);
        $(this).find('.price').attr("name", "price" + indice);
        $(this).find('.total').attr("name", "total" + indice);

    });
}

RemoveTableRow = function(handler) {
    var tr = $(handler).closest('tr');
    tr.fadeOut(400, function() {
        tr.remove();
    });

    ajustarNomes();
    return false;
};


AddTableRow = function() {

    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    
    var cols = "";

    cols += '<td class="col-md-4"><input type="text" class="form-control product" name="product"></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control amount" name="amount"></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="price"></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-md-2 total"><input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="total"></td>';
    cols += '<td class="col-md-2">';
    cols += '<a onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button"><i class="zmdi zmdi-delete zmdi-hc-lg"></i></a>';
    cols += '</td>';


    newRow.append(cols);
    $("#products-table").append(newRow);

    $(".amount, .price").unbind('blur keyup');
    $(".amount, .price").on("blur keyup",function(){
        const tr = $(this).parent().parent();

        const quant = parseInt(tr.find('.amount').val());
        const valor = parseInt(tr.find('.price').val());
        var total = quant * valor;

        if (!isNaN(quant) && !isNaN(valor)){
            tr.find('.total').html('<input readonly type="text" class="form-control" name="total" value=" '+total+' ">');
        }
    });
    
    ajustarNomes();
    return false;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table m-0" id="products-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Produto/Serviço</th>
        <th>Quantidade</th>
        <th>Valor Unitário</th>
        <th>Valor Total</th>
        <th>Remover</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="row">

</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
            <button class="btn btn-info waves-effect w-md waves-light m-b-5" onclick="AddTableRow()" type="button">Adicionar Produto</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>



</script>
```

Comment: Qual a diferença em colocar let num ao invés de var num?

Comment: @Marcelo A diferença está no escopo da variável, que com var é relativo à função ou ao `window` ao passo que em `let` é local ao bloco de chavetas onde foi declarado, à semelhança de uma variável normal como noutras linguagens. Existem ainda outras subtilezas para o `let` mas para o código acima não tem diferença e podia ter sido definido como `var`, foi mesmo questão de habito. Aconselho também a ler [a documentação do let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) caso tenha duvidas

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado.